# Umar ibn Khattab and Omar as a Western given name

Tags: arabia, given-name

The name "Omar" is used as a given name in Western countries, one of the most famous one is [Omar Bradley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omar_Bradley), a US World War 2 general. Is this given name related to the Islamic Caliph [Umar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umar%5d)? How did it come to be used in an English-speaking Christian-majority country like the US?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this [web posting](http://baheyeldin.com/culture/the-name-omar-in-the-western-hemisphere.html#comment-968) by Charles Kent Smith, former president of the [American Names Society](http://www.wtsn.binghamton.edu/ans/), he claims the popularity of Omar as the name of Americans in the 19th century (as in Omar Bradley) is due to the popularity of poems like the *Rubaiyat.* They are named after the famed poet [Omar Khayyam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omar_Khayy%C3%A1m), much the same way the names Homer or Milton or Virgil came into common usage.

Answer (score 10):

Omar occurs also in the bible

[Genesis 36:11](http://bible.cc/genesis/36-11.htm)

> The sons of Eliphaz: Teman, **Omar**, Zepho, Gatam and Kenaz.

[Genesis 36:15](http://bible.cc/genesis/36-15.htm):

> These were the chiefs among Esau's descendants: The sons of Eliphaz the firstborn of Esau: Chiefs Teman, **Omar**, Zepho, Kenaz,

[Chronicles 1:36](http://bible.cc/1_chronicles/1-36.htm) - same as Genesis 36:11

> The sons of Eliphaz: Teman, **Omar**, Zepho, Gatam and Kenaz;

Comment: ..which really shouldn't be all that shocking, as Hebrew and Arabic are both Semitic languages.

Comment: So this is the source of the Christian given name?

Comment: Dunno - we don't see as many (or any) Kenaz or Temans.